# Counting the number of occurrences of specific values in a list in specific intervals

Tags: list-manipulation, counting

If the variable "digits" contains 10,000 digits from 0 to 9. How can the number of occurrences of 1s and 2s be counted in every 1000 digit intervals, that is to say the number of 1s and 2s from 1 to 1000, the number of 1s and 2s from 1001 to 2000 and so on.

Comment: Seem a little strange advice, but you could use the capability of Mathematica in String Manipulation with [StringCount](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringCount.html) for example.

Comment: `{Count[#, 1], Count[#, 2]} & /@ Partition[digits, 1000]`

Answer (score 3):

Does "contains" mean it is a list, or a string, or a long integer?  You use the `list-manipulation` tag, so presumably a list.  If you want the total, you can

```
Count[1|2] /@ Partition[digits, 1000]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a smaller example (with  the list `digits` having 20 elements instead of 10000 and block size 5 instead of 1000):

```
n = 20;
bs = 5;

SeedRandom[1]
digits = RandomInteger[9, n]
{1, 4, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 6, 0, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 6}
```

You can use [`BlockMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html) in combination with `Counts`, `Tally`, `Count` or `BinCounts` as follows:

```
BlockMap[Counts, digits, bs]
```

> ```
> {<|1 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 0 -> 2, 7 -> 1|>,
>  <|0 -> 2, 8 -> 1, 6 -> 1,  4 -> 1|>, 
>  <|1 -> 3, 8 -> 1, 5 -> 1|>,
>  <|1 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 6 -> 1|>}
> ```

```
BlockMap[Tally, digits, bs]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1}, {4, 1}, {0, 2}, {7, 1}},
>  {{0, 2}, {8, 1}, {6, 1}, {4, 1}},
>  {{1, 3}, {8, 1}, {5, 1}}, 
>  {{1, 2}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {6, 1}}}
> ```

If a list of counts for each number from 0 to 9 in each block is desired:

```
BlockMap[Counts[#] /@ Range[0, 9] /. Missing -> (0 &) &, digits, bs]
```

> ```
> {{2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
>  {2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 
>  {0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
>  {0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}}
> ```

```
BlockMap[Through[(Count /@ Range[0, 9])@#] &, digits, bs]
```

> ```
> {{2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
>  {2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 
>  {0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
>  {0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}}
> ```

```
BlockMap[BinCounts[#, {0, 10, 1}] &, digits, bs]
```

> ```
> {{2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
>  {2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 
>  {0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
>  {0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}}
> ```